# ReferenceError: $anchorScroll is not defined

Tags: angularjs

From the documentation and another examples it really seems to me I am using this correctly.  However, in Chrome console I get the error:
$anchorScroll is not defined.

The click function that triggers this is in the code below called viewBugForm().

```
  feedbackModule.controller('feedbackController', ['$scope', '$timeout','$location','commonService',
                        function ($scope, $timeout, $location, commonService) {

                            scroll = () => {
                                $timeout(()  => {
                                    $location.hash('bug-form');
                                    $anchorScroll();
                                });
                            }

                            $scope.viewBugForm = (type) =>
                            {
                                 scroll();
                            }
```

Here is the anchor:

```
<a id="bug-form"></a>
```

Frankly I cannot find anything wrong.  I have tried with and without the timeout.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't importing $anchorScroll

Dumb mistake.  I thought it came from $location